# Использование сторонних библиотек в opensource проекте

Tags: github, авторские-права

Ситуация:

Существует проект на github, который для своей работы использует 2 сторонних библиотеки, а именно:

1) https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp

2) https://github.com/nlohmann/json#json-as-first-class-data-type

Но они используются не как ссылки на репозитории, а как скопированный код.

Вопрос: Каким образом необходимо обозначить авторов этих библиотек в репозитории проекта? Хватит ли ссылки в ReadMe или необходимо сделать еще что-то? И какие в теории могут быть проблемы с авторскими правами?